# Unable to undo changes even after $event.preventDefault - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

[***FIDDLE LINK***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/mpnyL6pv/)

I was prevent ng-click event, but ng-model value will be change after ng-click event complete. How to mantain the old value in ng-model when event is block.

This scenario event is bloked, but model value will change.

**Html code**

```
<form name="form1" class="form-horizontal">
    <div ng-app="scrollApp">
        <div ng-controller="scrollController">
            <div ng-grid="ngGridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>
            <div id="disSelectItems" ng-repeat="item in selectedGridItems">
                <label class="select-items {{item.selectedClass}}" ng-click="rowScroll(item)">{{item.entity.date}}</label>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Js Code**

```
angular.module("scrollApp", ['ngGrid', 'ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller("scrollController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedGridItems = [];
    $scope.test = [{
        "id": 1,
            "date": "oct 02/2014",
            "details": "test1",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "date": "oct 03/2014",
            "details": "test2",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "date": "oct 03/2014",
            "details": "test3",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 4,
            "date": "oct 04/2014",
            "details": "test4",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 5,
            "date": "oct 05/2014",
            "details": "test5",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 6,
            "date": "oct 06/2014",
            "details": "test6",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 7,
            "date": "oct 07/2014",
            "details": "test7",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 8,
            "date": "oct 08/2014",
            "details": "test8",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 9,
            "date": "oct 09/2014",
            "details": "test9",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 10,
            "date": "oct 10/2014",
            "details": "test10",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "date": "oct 11/2014",
            "details": "test11",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 12,
            "date": "oct 12/2014",
            "details": "test12",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 13,
            "date": "oct 13/2014",
            "details": "test13",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }, {
        "id": 14,
            "date": "oct 14/2014",
            "details": "test14",
            "check": false,
            "check1": false
    }]
    $scope.ngGridOptions = {
        data: 'test',
        multiSelect: false,
        columnDefs: [{
            field: "id",
            displayName: "ID",
            width: "50px"
        }, {
            field: "date",
            displayName: "Date",
            width: "100px"
        }, {
            field: "details",
            displayName: "Details"
        }, {
            field: "check",
            displayName: "",
            cellTemplate: "<div class='ngCellText'>{{COL_FIELD}}<input type='checkbox' ng-click='selectClick($event)' ng-checked='COL_FIELD' ng-model='COL_FIELD' /></div>",
            width: "50px"
        }]
    }

    $scope.selectClick=function($event)
    {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
    };   
});
```